# Scrapy not collecting properly emails

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to collect some data and everything works fine except the email extraction part. For some reason email row in .csv file is blank or there is only a few emails extracted. I've tried limiting download_delay and CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT but it's not working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import re
import scrapy


class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["hanford.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://hanford.craigslist.org/search/cto?min_auto_year=1980&min_price=3000"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://hanford.craigslist.org/'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        match = re.search(r"(\w+)\.html", response.url)
        if match:
            item_id = match.group(1)
            url = self.BASE_URL + "reply/sdo/cto/" + item_id

            item = DmozItem()
            item["link"] = response.url
            item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
            item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0])
            return scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_contact)

    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a quote from [Terms of Use](https://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use) as a warning:

> USE. You agree not to use or provide software (except for general
>   purpose web browsers and email clients, or software expressly licensed
>   by us) or services that interact or interoperate with CL, e.g. for
>   downloading, uploading, posting, flagging, emailing, search, or mobile
>   use. **Robots, spiders, scripts, scrapers, crawlers, etc. are
>   prohibited**, as are misleading, unsolicited, unlawful, and/or spam
>   postings/email. You agree not to collect users' personal and/or
>   contact information ("PI").

Several things to fix here:

- the contact information is under `reply/hnf/cto/` instead of `reply/sdo/cto/`
- specify `User-Agent` and `X-Requested-With` headers

The complete code that works for me:

```
import re
from urlparse import urljoin

import scrapy


class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["hanford.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://hanford.craigslist.org/search/cto?min_auto_year=1980&min_price=3000"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://hanford.craigslist.org/'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = urljoin(self.BASE_URL, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url,
                                 callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        match = re.search(r"(\w+)\.html", response.url)
        if match:
            item_id = match.group(1)
            url = urljoin(self.BASE_URL, "reply/hnf/cto/" + item_id)

            item = DmozItem()
            item["link"] = response.url
            item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
            item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0])
            return scrapy.Request(url,
                                  meta={'item': item},
                                  callback=self.parse_contact,
                                  headers={"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                                           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36"})

    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Comment: @ArkanKalu note that not every ad has the contact email - there are often phone numbers instead.

Comment: Yes i know that, but there is also a large percentage of posts which contain email but program skips them.

Comment: @ArkanKalu you know what also helped me - add a delay between requests using `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`.

Comment: For how long do you delay requests?

Comment: @ArkanKalu I think I've played around with values from 2 to 10.

Comment: @ArkanKalu to make things clearer - this is an anti web-scraping solution in action. They explicitly state they don't want to be scraped and they work against it - you should respect it and not to do anything illegal. If you would see into the `response.body` of the contact information response, you may find the "recaptcha" page there instead of actual contact information. This may cause empty contact email fields.

Comment: I know i am using this software for knowledge purposes only. Thanks for help so far i'll test it out with increased download_delay.